# javascript validation

Tags: javascript

I have two radio buttons. Each one has one associated text box. If I click one radio button and then submit an alert box should be shown if the associated text box is empty. How can I achieve this?

```
<form action="#" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return check_workorder()">
     <input type="radio" name="click" id="click1" checked="checked" value="date"/>
            <strong>Start Date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="text" id="my_date_field" name="my_date_field" class="datepicker" style="width:80px;"/>
              </strong>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            new Control.DatePicker('my_date_field', { icon: 'images/calendar.png' });
            </script>
            </br><br />
            <input type="radio" name="click" id="click2" value="order" />
            <strong>Work order no
            <input type="text" name="workno" id="workno" style="width:100px;"/>
            </strong><span class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return check_workorder()"/>
```

the javascript is

```
function check_workorder() {
    if (document.forms.form1.elements.click.value == "date") {
        var dat = (form1.my_date_field.value);
        if (dat == "") {
            alert("please select date");
            return false;
        }
    } else if (document.forms.form1.elements.click.value == "order") {
        var wor = (form1.workno.value);
        if (wor == "") {
            alert("please enter work order no");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, Can you show us the method you have written so far ? so that we can help with the specific issue you have.

Comment: Hi Dinesh. It's generally best to submit some code with a question like this, and to include as much information as possible. For example are you using something like jQuery or do you want to do the validation using plain old JavaScript?

Comment: Show the html for the inputs and radio buttons too please.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.forms.form1.elements.click.value == "date") {
    if (document.forms.form1.elements.click.checked) {
    //the radio button is checked
    }
}
```